# Unity - Why iPhone 6 and 7 behaves differently to touch input?

Tags: ios, iphone, unity-game-engine, input, touch

I have below code in Update() to drag camera and also detect clicks on objects. When we try on iphone 6 and X it works all well, but when we try on iPhone7 the drag screen is very unresponsive and clicking objects works only when you touch the screen very very lightly. Anybody have an idea on what is going on?

```
if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began) {
             fingerMoved = false;

             if (_eventSystem.IsPointerOverGameObject(Input.GetTouch(0).fingerId)) {
                 fingerMoved = true;
             }
             hit_position = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
             camera_position = cam.position;
         } else if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved) {
             current_position = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
             LeftMouseDrag();

             if (Vector2.Distance(hit_position, current_position) > 7f) {
                 fingerMoved = true;
             }

             cam.DOMoveY(target_position.y, 0.75f);
         } else if (!fingerMoved && Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Ended) {
             foreach (var item in storageList) {
                 if (Vector2.Distance(item.transform.position, Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(hit_position)) < 0.5f) {
                     sideMenu.Open(item.myNo);
                 }
             }
         }
 void LeftMouseDrag() {
     Vector3 direction = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(current_position) - Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(hit_position);
     direction.x = 0f;
     direction = direction * -1;
     target_position = camera_position + direction;
     if (target_position.y > camMaxY) {
         target_position.y = camMaxY;
     }
     if (target_position.y < camMinY) {
         target_position.y = camMinY;
     }
 }
```

Comment: It has to be related to UI sensibility. I've had the same problem on android.

Comment: Any resolution? What do you mean by UI sensibility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has gone by itself, I have no idea what went wrong at first.

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure if it makes a difference but for this kind of stuff its easier and more reliable to use EventSystems and OnPointerClick / OnPointerDrag hanlders. This way, at least in theory, any sensitivity differences could be leveled out by Unity itself. (I am not aware weather it does it or not its just

Comment: I cannot use it because of the _eventSystem.IsPointerOverGameObject() that I use to avoid false clicks underneath the UI.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and fixed it by adding the second line of the code displayed below.

```
else if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
if (master.calcDelta(Input.GetTouch(0).position) > 0f)
```

Which in turn, calculates the length of the vector that represents the dislocation from the previous location to the actual one.

```
calculatedDelta = Mathf.Abs(_touchPos.magnitude - pastPos.magnitude);
```

What is does is prevents the jittering from interfering with the built in function from unity "TouchPhase.Moved".